# Issues after Inserting Certain Code in index.html

Tags: sapui5

I am new to SAP UI5 and Fiori. I am developing my first application in SAP Web IDE. Very simple one - it has 2 views. I am trying to navigate from one view to another and facing issues. I think I am not declaring my views properly. My main view was working properly but after I inserted certain code in *index.html*, it started throwing errors. Also it says `navTo` method in controller is `undefined`. Sometimes, I get error saying `sap` is `undefined`. I think I am missing some libs also.

### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>temp_test</title>

    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
      src="https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
      data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
      data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
      data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
      data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"temp_test": "./"}'
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script>
      sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
        sap.ui.xmlview("MainPage1",{
          viewName: "temp_test.view.xmlnamepage"
        }).placeAt("content");
        /*sap.ui.xmlview("OrderMgmt1",{
          viewName : "temp_test.view.testingagain"
        }).placeAt("content");*/
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="sapUiBody" id="content"></body>
</html>
```

### MainView.Controller

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "sap/m/MessageToast",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
  "jquery.sap.global"
], function(Controller, MessageToast, JSONModel, jQuery) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("temp_test.controller.xmlnamepage", {
    onInit: function () {
      //moved to Component
    },

    press: function(evt) {
      MessageToast.show("The GenericTile is pressed.");
    },

    orderMgmt: function(evt) {
      var context = evt.getSource().getBindingContext();
      this.getRouter().navTo("OrderMgmt1");
    },

  });
});
```

### xmlnamepage.xml

```xml
<mvc:View
  controllerName="temp_test.controller.xmlnamepage"
  xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  displayBlock="true"
>
  <App>
    <Page title="Inventory Management">
      <l:VerticalLayout width="100%">
        <Panel class= "T2" width="100%">
          <headerToolbar>
            <Toolbar class="T1">
              <Title  level="H2" text="Site Overview"/>
            </Toolbar>
          </headerToolbar>
          <FlexBox
            class="columns"
            alignItems="Center"
          >
            <Label
              text="Filter Stockroom"
              labelFor="input-a"
            />
            <SearchField id="input-a"
              width="340px"
              class="sapUiSmallMargin"
            />
            <Button
              text="Apply"
              type="Emphasized"
              class="sapUiSmallMarginEnd"
            />
            <Button
              text="Reset"
              type="Emphasized"
              class="sapUiSmallMarginEnd"
            />
          </FlexBox>
          <FlexBox
            height="50%"
            alignItems="Start"
            justifyContent="Start"
          >
            <GenericTile
              class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin sapUiTinyMarginTop tileLayout AA"
              header="Inventory"
              subheader="1000 Parts managed"
              frameType="TwoByOne"
              press="press"
            >
              <TileContent>
                <ImageContent src="sap-icon://inventory"/>
              </TileContent>
            </GenericTile>
            <GenericTile
              class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin sapUiTinyMarginTop tileLayout"
              header="Orders"
              subheader="Back Orders"
              frameType="TwoByOne"
              press="press"
            >
              <TileContent>
                <ImageContent src="sap-icon://inventory"/>
              </TileContent>
            </GenericTile>
          </FlexBox>
        </Panel>
        <Panel class="T2">
          <headerToolbar>
            <Toolbar class="T1">
              <Title level="H2" text="Views you have access to" />
            </Toolbar>
          </headerToolbar>
          <FlexBox
            height="50%"
            alignItems="Start"
            direction="Row"
            justifyContent="Start"
          >
            <GenericTile
              class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin sapUiTinyMarginTop tileLayout D"
              header="Order Management"
              press="orderMgmt"
            >
              <TileContent>
                <ImageContent src="sap-icon://order-status"/>
              </TileContent>
            </GenericTile>
            <GenericTile
              class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin sapUiTinyMarginTop tileLayout C"
              header="Payment Management"
              press="press"
            >
              <TileContent>
                <ImageContent src="sap-icon://monitor-payments"/>
              </TileContent>
            </GenericTile>
            <GenericTile
              class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin sapUiTinyMarginTop tileLayout D"
              header="Stockroom Management"
              press="press"
            >
              <TileContent>
                <ImageContent src="sap-icon://product"/>
              </TileContent>
            </GenericTile>
            <GenericTile
              class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin sapUiTinyMarginTop tileLayout D"
              header="Supplier Management"
              press="press"
            >
              <TileContent>
                <ImageContent src="sap-icon://supplier"/>
              </TileContent>
            </GenericTile>
            <items class= "FI">
            <FeedInput
              post="onPost"
              icon="sap-icon://inventory"
              class="sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom FI"
            />
            <List
              showSeparators="Inner"
              items="{/EntryCollection}"
            >
              <FeedListItem
                sender="{Author}"
                icon="{AuthorPicUrl}"
                senderPress="onSenderPress"
                iconPress="onIconPress"
                iconDensityAware="false"
                info="{Type}"
                timestamp="{Date}"
                text="{Text}"
                convertLinksToAnchorTags="All"
              />
            </List>
          </FlexBox>
        </Panel>
      </l:VerticalLayout>
    </Page>
  </App>
</mvc:View>
```

### testingagain.xml

```xml
<mvc:View
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  controllerName="temp_test.controller.testingagain"
>
  <App>
    <Page title="new test title">
    </Page>
  </App>
</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please clarify your question first? 
You cannot use `var` inside an object, in your case you are trying to use it inside `sap.m.Shell` object. 
This `data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"temp_test": ""}'>` part of your code is wrong, you should point to some directory, e.g. `data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"temp_test": "./"}'>`
I would suggest you to try a [walk-through provided by SAP in their SDK](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db). 
Also, you might find helpful to go through [this course](https://open.sap.com/courses/ui51) first.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable inputs: I have redone my code and posted again on top. Now I do not get any error in index.html. But when I try to navigate to next view I keep getting error like  -  navTo is not a function.
I am now going step by step through walkthrough app process

Comment: Hi, @AratiDeshpande
You have a syntax error in your `index.html`, here `}).placeAt("content"),`, you should replace `,` with `;`
Could you please provide your XML views?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have edited. Main view is named xmlnamepage.xml and I tried but could not put it separately here. It went below Main Controller code. I really appreciate your response. I would be highly obliged if you could help me. I just need to understand this navigation. I went through entire walk through tutorial too but they have no eg to navigate from one view to other specially. Thakn you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a lookg at [Navigation and Routing](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/1b6dcd39a6a74f528b27ddb22f15af0d)

What your missing is in your manifest.json you have to add something similar to this, which is covered in step 2 of the above link.

```
"routing": {
     "config": {
        "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
        "viewType": "XML",
        "viewPath": "sap.ui.demo.nav.view",
        "controlId": "app",
        "controlAggregation": "pages",
        "transition": "slide"
        "async": true
     },
     "routes": [{
        "pattern": "",
        "name": "appHome",
        "target": "home"
     }],
     "targets": {
        "home": {
           "viewId": "home",
           "viewName": "Home",
           "viewLevel" : 1
        }
     }
  }
```